# Globalize variables in php

Tags: php, global-variables

I have 2 files. Lets say :

first.php

```
$a = 'blah';
echo 'echo2='.$a;

function foo(){
global $a;
echo 'echo3='.$a;
return $a;
}
```

second.php

```
require_once(path/to/the/file/first.php);
echo 'echo='.$a;
$b = foo();
echo 'echo4='.$b;
```

running the second.php file I get the following output :

```
echo=blah
echo2=blah
echo3=
echo4=
```

My question is "why I can't access variable $a in the function foo !

Comment: There's also the syntax error with the `require_once`. If you don't give the exact code, you'll only get guesses, not answers. Specifically if the include occurs within a functions local variable scope, the `$a=` declaration won't be global.

Comment: the `register_globals` in php.ini is set to off. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

Change `$global` to `global`.  That should fix it.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

or use

```
 $GLOBALS["Your_var_without_dollar_sign"];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php